# How solve module name collision in Python?

Tags: python, name-collision

I have a module named websocket. For this module I want some tests and for these tests I `pip install` the appropriate module. The problem is that the installed module has the **exact same** name as my own module.

**Project structure**:

```
websocket-server
       |
       |---- websocket.py
       |
       '---- tests
               |
               '---- test.py
```

**test.py**:

```
from websocket import WebSocketsServer  # my module
from websocket import create_connection # installed module
```

Is there a way to solve this:

- Without having to rename my module (`websocket.py`)
- Without polluting my project with ugly `__init__()`
- Needs to work both on Python3 and 2

Comment: Why is renaming your module off the table? That is exactly the solution.

Comment: @kindall because I don't want an other name. For me 'websocket' is the perfect name for my single-filed module.

Answer (score 5):

Can you nest your module in a package?

```
from mywebsocket.websocket import WebSocketsServer # my module
from websocket import create_connection # installed module
```

see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: probably the only proper answer, excluding hacks. If you have tests, you should have a package.

Comment: @goncalopp The end "product" is a single simple file. Making a package just for a single file feels too much.

Comment: What if you need to import create_connection to mywebsocket.websocket?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this in the end as I wanted. The solution is hackish but it doesn't matter since it's only for one specific type of tests.

```
import websocket as wsclient # importing the installed module

del sys.modules["websocket"]
sys.path.insert(0, '../..')
import websocket             # importing my own module
```

So I can now refer to my own module as `websocket` and the installed module as `wsclient`.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved a similiar problem with a dirty hack, which works only in UNIX/Linux.

In your root folder, make a soft link to itself:

```
> ln -s . myroot
```

Then just import whatever you want with the simple prefix:

```
import myroot.websocket
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an *imp* module - although it's on the way to be deprecated in Python 3.4. It allows you to import modules dynamically

```
my_websource = imp.load_source('my_websource', <path to your module.py>')
```

Comment: A Python 3.3+ solution here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path

Answer (score 0):

You could choose a different capitalization like webSocket, since the Python resolution is case-sensitive.